# Higher order function fixes parameters. Make it fix two parameters as equal

Tags: python

### Mock version of the problem

For a function

```py
def f(a,b,c):
  return a+b+c
```

The function

```py
def fix(func, **kwargs):
  fa = kwargs.get('a')
  fb = kwargs.get('b')
  if fa is not None and fb is not None:
    def f(*args):
      return func(a=fa, b=fb, c=args[0])
  elif fa is not None:
    def f(*args):
      return func(a=fa, b=args[0], c=args[1])
  elif fb is not None:
    def f(*args):
      return func(a=args[0],b=fb, c=args[1])
  else:
    def f(*args):
      return func(args)
  return f
```

allows to obtain a new function by fixing some of the parameters of `func`.

**For example:** `fix(g, b=3)` would give us a function like

```py
def fixed_b_in_g(a,c):
  return g(a,3,c)
```

**Question:** I would like to see if there is some trick to use `fix` in such a way that produces a function like

```py
def fix_a_equal_b_in_g(a,c):
  return g(a,a,c)
```

### Concrete problem

The function [`scipy.stats.rv_continuous.fit`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.rv_continuous.fit.html) allows to fit parameters of a distribution to an input sample. It allows to input some keyword arguments (like `fix` above does) to tell it to keep some of the parameters fixed to values that the user inputs. Internally `scipy.stats.rv_continuous.fit` has a function, `scipy.stats.rv_continuous._reduce_func`, that does more or less what `dix` does (better implemented than my `fix` for example).

In my case, rather than fixing some parameters to values, I would like to fit to keep two parameters (say `a` and `b`) equal to each other, but still free during the fitting.

Comment: Working on writing an answer for your actual question, but `fix` is just a specific keyword-arg-only version of `functools.partial`.

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding, but why can't you simply return `func(a=fa, b=fa, c=args[0])`?

Comment: So you don't have actually have a `fix` you can modify, only a function that behaves like `fix` shown does?

Comment: @PranavHosangadi What I am asking would be rather like returning `func(a=args[0], b=args[0], c=args[1])`. Strictly speaking I could modify `fix` by monkey patching it, but my question is rather if I would achieve the same by using `fix` as it is, from outside.

Comment: @chepner That is right, for the sake of my question. Strictly speaking replacing `fix` with a version of my own is actually possible, but I would like to see if it is possible to use `fix` as it is. The real `fix` is `scipy.stats.rv_continuous._reduce_func`.

Comment: `_reduce_func` doesn't appear to be documented (unsurprising, given its name). I'm not sure I'd spend a lot of time trying to figure out how to do much of anything with it.

Comment: @chepner Yes, it is an internal function of `scipy.stats.rv_continuous`, that is used by `scipy.stats.rv_continuous.fit`. I went into the code of the latter to see it. That is one of the reasons that I want to see if I could do something "from outside" `scipy.stats.rv_continuous.fit`, rather than monkey-patch `scipy.stats.rv_continuous._reduce_func`.

Answer (score 1):

We can use this function to copy a keyword argument whose name is `base_kwarg_name` to `added_kwarg_name`:

```
def with_copied_kwargs(func, added_kwarg_names_by_base):
    def fixed_func(*args, **base_kwargs):
        added_kwargs = {
            added_kwarg_name: base_kwargs[base_kwarg_name]
            for base_kwarg_name, added_kwarg_name in added_kwarg_names_by_base.items()
        }

        return func(*args, **base_kwargs, **added_kwargs)

    return fixed_func
```

Given:

```
def add(*, a, b, c):
    return a + b + c
```

then `modified_add = with_copied_kwargs(add, {"b": "c"})` is equivalent to:

```
def modified_add(*, a, b):
    return add(a=a, b=b, c=b)
```

`with_copied_kwargs` can then be used along with `functools.partial` to both both copy keyword arguments and provide values incrementally. `modified_add = functools.partial(with_copied_kwargs(add, {"b": "c"}), a=1)` is equivalent to:

```
def modified_add(*, b):
    return add(a=1, b=b, c=b)
```

Note that I add `*` (see [PEP 3102](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3102/)) before all parameters in functions I then apply `with_copied_kwargs` to because the minute people start using positional arguments, things would get messy. So better to restrict it to keyword-only arguments.

Comment: That is very good! But let me add that my wording in the question didn't make explicit that: The analogous of `fix` (`scipy.stats.rv_continuous._reduce_func`), in the concrete problem, is used inside `scipy.stats.rv_countinuous.fit`. The keyword parameters that allow fixing at part of the signature of `fit`. I wouldn't be able, I think, to wrap `fix` (`_reduce_func`) directly, but `fit` instead. I still need to learn and digest the content of your answer. It looks like everything I need is in there, with minor changes. Perhaps I can wrap `_reduce_func` and then monkey patch it into `scipy`.